# How to implement a threaded view?

Tags: vb6

I need to implement a threaded view of sorts in an old VB6 app.  It should look similar to this:

[image]

So, it's like a TreeView of sorts but there are buttons on the right (for each row) that could be pressed.  The view does not need to collapse - it always stays in the expanded mode.  The users should be able to respond to each node (via the comment button on the far right).  And, of course, users should be able to scroll through the entries.

What are some of the ways I could implement this?  I am open to 3rd party controls, paid or not.

Comment: Isn't it an option to write this in .Net and wrapping it in a ComVisible dll?

Answer (score 1):

VSFlexGrid has an outline mode.  You can set the indent per row via the RowOutlineLevel property.  It supports word wrap, images, etc within its cells/columns so you should be able to get pretty close to what you want.  It also supports owner-drawn which lets you fully customize the cell painting (for example, to get those rounded corners).

I'm sure there are other controls out there as well...